# VBScript Continues Loop to Rename File

Tags: vbscript, infinite-loop, wsh

Trying to create a VBScript that loops continuously until it finds the specific file and renames it to a different extension with minute and seconds:

```
do
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFile = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.txt")

If (fso.FileExists(myFile)) Then
     myFile.Move "C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.xml"
End If

WScript.Sleep 1000

loop
```

The above works and renames the file but when looped it errors with "file cannot be found". Will need to add a else statement but having a hard time doing that.

Comment: Because you move the file so the `Set myFile = fso.GetFile("C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.txt")` will fail on the second iteration. You should be checking the `.FileExists(full_file_path)` before trying to instantiate the `myFile` object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for the files existence first before attempting to instantiate the `File` object reference.

```
Dim fso, myFile, source, dest

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Do
  source = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.txt"
  dest = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\test.xml"

  If fso.FileExists(source) Then
    Set myFile = fso.GetFile(source)
    Call myFile.Move(dest)
    Set myFile = Nothing
  End If
  WScript.Sleep 1000
Loop

Set fso = Nothing
```

<sup>* *This is a pseudo coded example based on the original example*</sup>

Moved the `fso` instantiation outside of the loop to avoid re-instantiating it on each iteration.

At present not sure what purpose the loop serves but if you are going to be running this for long periods it best to un-instantiate any references to help with script memory optimisation by setting them to `Nothing`.

> Would also recommend while testing the loop to limit the iterations using a counter and exiting the loop if the count is exceeded.